# post data in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, post, curl

I have collected data and created and array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Martin
            [surname] => test
            [email] => martin@gmail.com
            [dob] => 2015-02-24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Kary
            [surname] => paulman
            [email] => kary@gmail.com
            [dob] => 2015-06-26
        )

)
```

I have multiple records in this array.

I want to post each record in the array to www.recieve.com , where it will pass a response of 'true' if post was successful and 'false' if it fails.

I have researched the interent and i dont even know where to start.

So far my code looks like this (this is just for the array)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$res[] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($res);   echo "</pre>";

I have tryed this and it is not working : 

//Build my array
$query = "SELECT * FROM applicants";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$res[] = $row;
}

//URL to post to
$url = 'https://theurl.com?';

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($res as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: If you use composer or something i would go for Guzzle. But curl would also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Curl and like this

```
$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/curl_example.php"; // where you want to post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=value1&var2=value2&var_n=value_n"); // define what you want to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute

curl_close ($ch); // close curl handle

var_dump($output); // show output

?>
```

Use your array in the : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your cURL request that I can see:

1. You are not encoding the values correctly for use in a query string
2. `$fields` is undefined.

You can solve that using for example:

```
// make sure the values are encoded correctly:
$fields_string = http_build_query($res);

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// you need the count of your `$res` variable here:
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($res));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Also note that you don't need a question mark at the end of the url. I don't know if that would cause problems, but you should probably just remove that:

```
$url = 'https://theurl.com';
```